# Is there a setting to keep empty lists during JSON serialization in ServiceStack?

Tags: json, servicestack

As the title says, is there a way to keep empty lists during JSON serialization in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack.Text JSON Serializer, already serializes empty lists by default:

```cs
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;

Console.WriteLine(new Test().ToJson());

public class Test
{
    public List<string> List { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Output:

```
{"List":[]}
```

Comment: I guess I was just tired…  thanks